# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated in codeigniter on PHP version 7.1

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

When I **encrypt** my **ID** using **encrypt library** that time it gives me an error like :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 2):

codeigniter already mention it on their official documentation of encrypt Library

> This library has been DEPRECATED and is only kept for backwards
>   compatibility. Please use the new [Encryption Library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html).

use new Encryption Library.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using php 7.2 and I can solve using the new library encryption recommend.

Example:

```
// #Encrypt

$this->load->library('encryption');
$to_encrypt="some value";
$this->encryption->initialize(
        array(
                'cipher' => 'aes-256',
                'mode' => 'ctr',
                'key' => $this->config->config['encryption_key']
        )
);
echo $this->encryption->encrypt($to_encrypt);
```

More Info ->  https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: also: use `$this->encryption->decrypt($var);` instead of *$this->encryption->decode($var)*