# how to upgrade Encryption Library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mcrypt

In one of existing CI project after upgrading php version to  7.1.18 mcrypt start showing some deprecated issue like:

- Message: Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated
- Message: Function mcrypt_encrypt() is deprecated

after searching on that I fond that This library is deprecated I need to use new library from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341314/function-mcrypt-get-iv-size-is-deprecated-in-codeigniter-on-php-version-7-1)

But I don't know how to download it and add it to my existing project which is on shared server.

How can i do that?

Comment: are you talking about `Codeigniter's` **encryption** library ?? or you are talking about `openssl`

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi yes Codeigniter's encryption library

Comment: I think that is part of system folder in codeigniter by default.

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi yes i guess but when i upgraded php v7.1 it is showing deprecated errors how can i fix this

Comment: Not Sure I think check your php installation for `openssl` or if not then install it instead of `mcrypt`. or in the `phpinfo` page check for openssl libraries is installed or not , if not then install it i hope that will solve the problem

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi as site is on shared server i don't have access to configuration file. So for now i have added error_reporting(E_ALL^E_DEPRECATED); to Encrypt.php in system/library file which suppress my error and page loads fine

Comment: try to create your own file having code for `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and try to show content even if not provide the details then mail the customer support center then will help